# Github pages not publishing website even after it is ready to be published

Tags: github-pages

Tried connecting to https://brandonchen1.github.io/ after github said your site is ready to be published. Tried opening website in different browsers and the repository is https://github.com/BrandonChen1/BrandonChen1.github.io.

Can anyone help me figure out why the webpage is still displaying a 404?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yea, sorry. Why is the webpage still showing a 404? I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Not showing a 404 to me..

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this question when my pages weren't getting published. Posting what I did in case someone else runs into this too.

Check [GH's status](https://www.githubstatus.com/) as suggested by [this community question](https://github.community/t/my-page-stuck-in-ready-to-be-published-status-at-least-few-hours-and-doesnt-publish/10580/3) and make sure everything is green.

Then check your repo's `Actions` tab. Under `Workflows`, look for `pages-build-deployment` or something similar and check for any errors in the runs. The `Actions` page can be found at `https://github.com/<username>/<repo name>/actions`.